# why flutter doesn't update the code changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing Confusing problem that when I do changes in some pages the code doesn't apply only when I close the app and reopen the whole app,
and other pages of the app doesn't have this problem

```
class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  double time;
  int discounted;
  PageOne(this.time,this.discounted);
  @override
  _EnterPhoneNumberState createState() => _EnterPhoneNumberState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String errorText;
  bool done = false;
  bool loading = false;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("test");
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      key:globalKey ,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xff007eff),
                    Color(0xff01b7fe),
                  ]
              )
          ),
        ),
        preferredSize: Size(size.width, 80),
      ),
      body:Container(
     
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and when I am changing some code in the main file the code in the class that I am facing this problem with working fine with hot reload or run

Comment: Please provide the code where this is happening.

Comment: please update your question with code

Comment: question is updated now

Comment: [setState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) ?

Comment: the problem when I do changes on code 
ex: change print("test") to print ("test 2") and press run app the app still print "test"  unless I close the whole app and reopen it, or do some change on code in main file